# jQuery loop through elements to enter text and change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to write a function to change the font colour of items in a table made up of cells each with ids. The Table has 18 columns and 49 rows, so I need to write the function to loop through all these entries.

The table div ids are named "Game1Player1, Game1Player2......Game49Player18

At the moment I populate these cells longhand, using a line of code for each cell

```
document.getElementById("Game1Player1").innerHTML = Game1Player1Name;
document.getElementById("Game1Player2").innerHTML = Game1Player2Name;
document.getElementById("Game49Player18").innerHTML = Game49Player18Name;
```

When i tried the following Javascript to add a class, it would not work, I could not see what was wrong

```
document.getElementById("Game1Player1").addClass += " Tsub1a";
```

However when I tried this JQuery function, it works a treat

```
$(document).ready( function() {
$('#Game1Player1').addClass( 'Tsub1a' );
} );
```

It would be nice to know why, but to solve my problem I prefer to use the JQuery function.

How do I make it a function that will loop through all 18 players and 49 games to change the font colour based on the condition if Game1Player1Sub === "Sub 1", Game1Player1Sub === "Sub 2",....up to "Sub 7"

I'm a complete novice when it comes to JQuery, so any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Your second last paragraph is unclear to me, what are you trying to ask?

Comment: Show (a representative, minimal, [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve/) of) your HTML as it starts, then show what it should look like *after* being processed with jQuery/JavaScript. And, while you want to assign font-colours, you haven't defined what colours, or how the colours relate to the text/content of the cells. Or even *if* the colour relates to the content of the cells. Please: consider reading this article (here on the site) "[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"

Comment: I'm asking how to make the JQuery function to loop through Game1Player1 to Player18, then Game2, up to Game 49.

Comment: Fair enough, from your description and 'explanation' I have no idea of how to help, which is why I asked you for specific information. But there's always a chance that someone else understands, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this - `$('div[id*=Game][id*=Player]')` to select all the elements.

Also, just to give you an idea, you can search attributes using patterns like these -

`$('div[id^=test]')` - Search for all divs with id starting with test

`$('div[id$=test]')` - Search for all divs with id endingwith test

`$('div[id*=test]')` - Search for all divs with test anywhere in the id

Your last paragraph is slightly confusing, but if I understand correctly, you'd like to iterate through the items and apply class accordingly, if so -

```
$('div[id*Game][id*Player]').each(function(index, item){
    $(item).addClass('Tsub' + item.id.split('Player')[1] + 'a');
});
```

If not, please rephrase the question so we can understand correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your table cells would also have a class on them so you could write line two as:

```
$(".game-player").addClass("tsub1a");
```

jQuery will collect all cells with this class into an object and apply addClass() to them all.